# can you souf in hexadecimal but with a limited amout of spaces ? java

Tags: java, format

my question is simple I am trying to format some code in hexadecimal but with a limited amount of space.
my code right now is

```
System.out.printf("%02X",file.read())
```

that codes formats in hexadecimal and works, but I also need it to do

```
System.out.printf("%45s",file.read())
```

which from what I tested puts a limit of 45 characters. Is there a way I could put the %45s and the %02X in the same command. Which would result in my file.read() being formatted in hexadecimal but with a limit of 45 characters per row.

Edit : my codes works perfectly I only need a way to put these 2 commands together

Comment: What is the type of `file.read`?

Comment: my file.read() reads every character in int

Comment: You wrote `file.read`, not `file.read()`.  Please correct your question. Also, how can an `int` rendered as hex be 45 characters wide?

Comment: i corrected it and there is more than  1 int. Basically what my code does it takes every character in the file and puts every single character as a int after that I take every single int and put them in hexadecimal. to get the result I want I need to be able to do %45s and %02X idk if 45s mean 45 characters wide or spaces wide but i know its how wide my formats need to be

Comment: The reader is left to assume what `file` is - if it is a `FileInputStream` then `file.read()` reads _one byte_ returned as an int.  You likely need a read loop (also checking for -1).

Comment: What is `souf`?

Comment: souf is System.out.printf

Comment: I only need a way to get the 2 commands together I don't understand why the type of the file or the type of the output is important ?

Comment: my file is a RandomAccessFile

Comment: `limit of 45 characters per row.` - no the `%45s` causes the output to occupy _at least_ 45 characters - right-justified with leading padding of spaces - more than 45 would still print all characters of string.  Also if the `read()` only reads _one byte_ then it is hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: bassicly what i need is a way to make each line of the printf 45 charachters wide

Comment: Try ```System.out.printf("%43s%02X%n", " ", file.read());```

Comment: *"souf is System.out.printf"* - Please don't use dubious abbreviations that most other Java programmers are unlikely to understand.  (I assume that you >do< want people to understand your questions ....)

Comment: Ah ... I see ... it is an Intellij shortcut.  Well only a small percentage of Java programmers use Intellij.  And only a fraction of them will have memorized the shortcut names.   My point stands.

Answer (score 1):

[`FileInputStream#read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) reads 1 byte (returned as an `int`). If you want to print 45-byte (ie 90 hex characters) long lines of bytes read, use a loop to print an end of line every 45 reads:

```
FileInputStream file;
for (int i = 1; file.available() > 0; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%02X",file.read());
    if (i % 45 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```